# How to save and retrieve files to apps temp folder in ios

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I'm new to IOS development. I'm developing an app which involves downloading files and saving that to apps temp folder and I dont know how to do that my current code is given below

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",tmpDirURL);
NSString *myString = [tmpDirURL absoluteString];
for(int i=0;i<responseArray.count;i++){
    ASIHTTPRequest *saveUrl  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:responseArray[i]];
    [saveUrl setDownloadDestinationPath:myString];
    [request startSynchronous];
}
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myString error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",directoryContents);
```

The response array contain a list of URL for downloading files.  I know something wrong with my code but I cant find out that error please help me to solve this problem

Comment: What do you observe? Log error variables.

Comment: As a side note: ASIHTTPRequest is an old library, its development stopped few years ago. It might be a good idea to use something newer, like AFNetworking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution'

```
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *htmlFilePath = [documentsDirectory  stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
        [data writeToFile:htmlFilePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: This is user's documents folder, it's not for storing temp files.

Answer (score 0):

When downloadDestinationPath is set, the result of this request will be downloaded to the file at this location. If downloadDestinationPath is not set, download data will be stored in memory

```
NSURL *tmpDirURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() isDirectory:YES];
NSLog(@"%@",tmpDirURL);
NSString *myString = [tmpDirURL absoluteString];
for(int i=0;i<responseArray.count;i++){
    ASIHTTPRequest *saveUrl  = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:responseArray[i]];
    [saveUrl setDownloadDestinationPath:[myString stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i ]]; // for each file set a new location inside tmp
    [request startSynchronous];
}
NSError * error;
NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:myString error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",directoryContents);
```